# Should we approve or reject syntax highlighting-only suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

There just were some syntax highlighting-only edits in the Suggested Edits queue. These edits were approved, but I rejected them because these edits are too minor in my opinion. Sometimes, I also do syntax highlighting-only edits, but then that's not a suggested edit, and I think it is too minor as a suggested edit but acceptable as a 'normal' edit.

Of course, I might be wrong, so that's why I'm asking here. Should be approve or reject syntax highlighting-only suggested edits?

<sub>Note: this question is not the same question as ["Mass editing of syntax highlighting - good or bad?"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1109/9275) because that question is about edits and my question is about *suggested* edits.</sub>

Comment: Same difference. Same arguments apply.

Comment: I've been approving them, since I feel they make code more legible. I don't see a difference between suggested and not in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally approve it unless

1. the post is very old (I approved [these](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10863) [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10864) old post edits today because I didn't notice the date, sorry about that)
2. the language code used in that edit is invalid (I've seen [lang-julia](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10869), [lang-r](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10861) and [lang-clojure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10867) in suggested edits but [these codes do not actually exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/259700), there is no support for Julia and R and the correct code for Clojure is lang-clj)
3. the code is so short it doesn't make any difference in readability (e.g. `print "Hello world"`, or [this suggested edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/10872))

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I didn't realize some of the language codes didn't exist, because apart from one of my edits, they all seemed correctly highlighted.

Comment: @nyuszika7h: They all seemed correctly highlighted, because if a language code is invalid, it just uses the "default" highlighting.